# Is there a way to use the search functions of synaptic from the command line?

Tags: package-management, apt, synaptic

I love Synaptic's ability to search the repo for both installed and uninstalled packages, but I would like to use this same ability through the apt command line utility, so I can search for packages from a shell.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah use `aptitude`!

If you want to search for something out of the installed packages try:

```
aptitude search '~i <other search terms>'
```

And you can negate the `~i` so this would search packages that are **not** installed:

```
aptitude search '!~i <other search terms>'
```

`aptitude` can do a stupid amount of stuff and it's sad to see it being removed from future versions of Ubuntu (by default - you can still install it).

You can [read more about `aptitude`'s search terms here](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could search for packages with `apt-cache`, searching for a pattern is like

```
apt-cache search <pattern>
```

If you only want to search in package names

```
apt-cache --names-only search <pattern>
```

Pattern are regular expressions, but be aware to protect them from shell expansion. If you use more than one pattern, they are and'ed together.

The output is the short description, if you want a long one, use the `--full` option.

Also, `aptitude` can do more specific searches, for example something like

```
aptitude search '?installed?not(?automatic)?priority("optional")?name("^s")'
```

but `aptitude` is not installed by default.